# Runtime permissions returns every time denied

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-audiorecord

i got an issue with the  AUDIO_RECORD permission

In short : - AUDIO_RECORD permission returns always false.

When the user starts the app (firs-time) it shows the  permission request 
message dialog 
if the user accepts,denies it all works good.
Next time when the user opens the app i check if the permission are granted, it returns permission denied and i request permissions again.
And every time when starting the microphone to record. It returns permission denied and i have to request again permissions. So every time i start microphone it returns  permission denied.
My problem is that the app  should work in background and start recording from a widget for example, but starting the permission request it brings the activity in front.

```
int permissionResult = PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    // Start listening to voices
    if (permissionResult == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_DENIED || permissionResult == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_DENIED_APP_OP) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions( new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);
        }
    } else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
        showPermissionMessageDialog();
    } else if (permissionResult == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     //granted.
    }


 private void showPermissionMessageDialog() {
    MessageDialogFragment
            .newInstance(getString(R.string.permission_message))
            .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_MESSAGE_DIALOG);
}
```

MessageDialogFragment

```
/**
 * A simple dialog with a message.
 *
 *  <p>The calling {@link android.app.Activity} needs to implement {@link
 * MessageDialogFragment.Listener}.</p>
 */
   public class MessageDialogFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

public interface Listener {
    /**
     * Called when the dialog is dismissed.
     */
    void onMessageDialogDismissed();
}

private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";

/**
 * Creates a new instance of {@link MessageDialogFragment}.
 *
 * @param message The message to be shown on the dialog.
 * @return A newly created dialog fragment.
 */
public static MessageDialogFragment newInstance(String message) {
    final MessageDialogFragment fragment = new MessageDialogFragment();
    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            .setMessage(getArguments().getString(ARG_MESSAGE))
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialog, which) -> ((Listener) getActivity()).onMessageDialogDismissed())
            .setOnDismissListener(dialogInterface -> ((Listener) getActivity()).onMessageDialogDismissed())
            .create();
}

}
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="....">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: What does `showPermissionMessageDialog()` look like?

Comment: @LarrySchiefer Updated the post, Also got a solution with a library.

 It would be better if i could get why my approach didnt worked so i can learn about my mistake.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more code and also what `PermissionChecker` is doing. If you are interested in a library to make this simpler, take a look at andele: https://github.com/hiqes/andele